# non-italic numbering and text in theorem

Tags: theorems

```
\documentclass{aip-cp}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{conjecture}{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{define}{Definition}

\begin{document} 

\begin{theorem}  Let $t(G)= \mathrm{something \  dummy} $. Then 
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item $t(P_r)=r$; 
    \item $t(K_m \times P_r)= r+1 \ \mathrm{for} \  m \geq 2$;
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

Hi, as above.

How can i make the the numbering and the text "something dummy " and "for" as normal text n non-italic?

Thank you.

Comment: For the first, why don't you just put the closing `$` before `something dummy`? For the second, if you are loading `mathtools` or `amsmath`, try `\text{for}`. Otherwise `\mathrm{for}` for serif or `\mathsf{for}` for sans.

Comment: `\mathrm{}` is really for upright serif which is maths. So `\text{}` would definitely be better here if you are really typesetting text.

Comment: Hi, \mathrm{for}  works well. But what about the numbering? and \text{ } does not work.

Comment: Since we don't even know how the `theorem` environment is defined, how should we comment on the numbering? If you could provide a complete example (`\documentclass... \end{document}`), we'd be more help.

Comment: The numbering is consistent with the surrounding text. If you wish to change this, you can use [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) or issue `\rmfamily` before the `enumerate` environment.

Comment: Hi, I edited the text and includes the theorem environment. I am sorry if this is correct. Still very new to it,

Answer (score 4):

With `enumitem` use this code:

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*,font=\upshape]
\item …
\end{enumerate}
```

Or even, if you don't want to have to type the optional argument each time, add this to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{theorem}{\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\arabic*,font=\upshape}}
```

Comment: Don't you need to say at the beginning of *which* environment?

Comment: Oops! Thought of it, and found it was enough, probably· Thanks for pointing it. 'Tis corrected now.